# why using of explicit is causing compiler error

Tags: c++

I have seen many post regarding explicit keyword but no where find the answer for why its failing. I have seen other post in stack overflow also but Regarding the conversion its very confusing kind of explanation given

```
class Foo {
public:
  explicit Foo(int x);
};
int main()
{
Foo a = 42;         //Compile-time error 
Foo b(42);          //OK: calls Foo::Foo(int) passing 42 as an argument
}
```

what exactly happening when we are writing `Foo a = 42;` , and how its differ from `Foo b(42);`

Comment: Perhaps you could share the error with us? Do you know what explicit means for a constructor?

Comment: error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Foo' requested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the explicit keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean)

Comment: Not duplicate, In that post there was no explanation for what  asked

Comment: So you're saying that this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19250874/920069 is not exactly what you're asking about?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/19250874/920069 , here its not explained of failure case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo a = 42;
```

if a constructor can be called with a single parameter, then it is a conversion constructor.Single argument can be converted to the class being constructed.

To disallow this you mark the constructor as explicit so such implicit conversions are not allowed, hence the error.

Comment: if implicit conversions are not allowed then how its working for Foo b(42);

Comment: `Foo b(42)` is not implicit constructor call. `Foo a = 42` is.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo a = 42;` is *copy initialisation*.

And the C++ standard states that

> explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not
>   considered for copy-initialization.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

So it's a, perhaps lesser-known, effect of `explicit`.